# Rails 4 Passing ajax request parameters to controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been using the geocoder gem but since the geolocator from the ip_address is way of I've been trying to solve this by using and AJAX request. Tried POST method but than I get a routing error so tried a GET instead and the SQL in my logs controller window seems to work but I can't see anything appear on the page itself and can't access the params[] hash either. Anyone see what I've done wrong?

Company_addresses_controller.rb

```
def index_close_ones
  #@company_addresses = CompanyAddress.near([50.50, 30.20], 10, units: :km) does work
  @company_addresses = CompanyAddress.near([params[:lat], params[:lon]], 10, units: :km) #doesn't work
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'closetome' => 'company_addresses#index_close_ones'
```

welcome index.html.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p><a onclick="getLocation()" href="/closetome" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Close to you</a></p>

<!--For testing purposes-->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
//for testing
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locate);}
    else{alert("Not supported in this browser");}
}

function locate(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    var latitude = crd.latitude;
    var longitude = crd.longitude;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/closetome",
    data: { lat: latitude, lon: longitude },
    success: function(data){
      return false},
    error: function(data){
      return false}
    });
    //for testing
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude:" + latitude + "<br>Longitude:" +longitude;
}
</script>    
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `@company_addresses = CompanyAddress.near([params[:lat].to_f, params[:lon].to_f], 10, units: :km)`

Comment: I just did but the problem is that I can't seem to access the params[] hash, which is quite strange. So the to_f method gives back 0.0, 0.0

Comment: remove  `href="/closetome"`from your anchor tag. It is posting your form directly. Also include `event.preventDefault()` in your `geolocation()` code.

Comment: and then putton the anchor tag and script in the same view that gets populated I guess?

Comment: Not sure what you asking about? Have you get any error on this?

Comment: does it work when you go directly on /closetome?lat=37.7749295&lon=-122.4194155   ??

Comment: Used your coords and that's why it didn't work the first time but now replaced it with my coords and it did work now. But how do I get the javascript var correctly in the params hash now...

Comment: http://localhost:3000/closetome?lat=37.7749295&lon=-122.4194155&_=1412173184212 is what I see as the Request URL when using the "Inspect element" function from chrome